# Where is the registry location to add an item to "My Computer/This PC" background context menu?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, windows-registry, context-menu

When right-clicking on the blank area of "My Computer/This PC", usually a context menu appears as follows:

[image]

Is it customizable or is there a registry location corresponding to this menu?

For instance, if I want to add a "CMD Here" item to the Desktop background context menu, all I need to do is to add some values to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell` according to the following `.reg` file.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\CMD Here]
@="&CMD Here"
"Icon"="CMD.exe"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\CMD Here\Command]
@="CMD /K PUSHD \"%W\" & TITLE %W"
```

Of course My Computer/This PC is possibly a special place where `%W` or `%V` won't work. However it is still favorable to know if such method can be working on My Computer/This PC. Is writing a DLL a must?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I will convert the url to image after having more reputation. Thanks immediately if someone edited it already.

Comment: [Edit] your question to include what exactly you are trying to add.  There are inherit limits on what can be added to the menu in question